# How to get the data from the Arduino fast

Tags: microcontroller-kit

I have a project to get data from a few sensors from the Arduino. I need the data to be sampled not less than 200 Hz.

I am trying to use the Wolfram for this task but when I use the `DeviceRead` it is not fast enough to transfer the data to Mathematica compare to the Arduino IDE.

Look at the reading rate:

[image]

How to get the data fast in Wolfram similar to the case when using  Arduino IDE serial plotter or serial monitor?